# convert any string like "10", "-0.129894", "12.02102" to number without adding or loosing anything

Tags: javascript

As you can see from the title I have various cases for strings that can contain numbers in them. I found out that using `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` didn't work for me as parseInt will convert number like 10.28 to just 10, but parseFloat will make number like 10 into 10.0, I want to somehow convert string into number so it stays exactly like it was in the string without anything removed or added.

Comment: Well, `parseFloat("12.02102")` will give you `12.02102` only. What are you trying to ask?

Comment: And `parseFloat("10")` should give you `10`, not `10.0` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [MDN Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) ( [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dwab3ed2(v=vs.94)) page also, but not so much info ). 
At the top of the page:

> The primary uses for the **Number** object are:
>
> - If the argument cannot be converted into a number, it returns [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).
> - In a non-constructor context (i.e., without the [new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) operator), Number can be used to perform a type conversion.

At the bottom of the page, there are some examples:

> ```
> Convert numeric strings to numbers
>
> Number("123")     // 123
> Number("")        // 0
> Number("0x11")    // 17
> Number("0b11")    // 3
> Number("0o11")    // 9
> Number("foo")     // NaN
> Number("100a")    // NaN
> ```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/hxkfafdw/

More on the topic - `Number("foo")` is `NaN` `Number("f00")` - same. `Number("0xf000")` - this is a hex number.

Comment: Is Number(s) just a longer version of  +s  ?   The output from both methods appear to be identical.

Comment: @Roberto + is used to concatenate strings, in general. Yes, it works, but it is just not right in my opinion. This kind of micro-optimization is not worth it.

Comment: @Roberto take a look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dwab3ed2(v=vs.94)) - the second paragraph of the Remarks, explains about the conversion toString() when '+' is used. This is another point, for me at least, why not to use it for casting.

Comment: Thanks, that was very interesting. It says the plus operator returns a string whenever any of the parameters is a string. And so Number is the better option.